# Upgrade magento from 1.8.1 to 1.9.38. Error: Failed to open File

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade

*I tried to update last magento 1 version but after installation some packages are  giving below error:*

**CONNECT ERROR**:

Failed to open file:
 C:/wamp/www/mysite\downloader.cache\community\Interface_Adminhtml_Default-1.9.3.8\app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/sales/order/invoice/create/items/renderer
    Failed to open file C:/wamp/www/mysite\downloader.cache\community\Interface_Frontend_Rwd_Default-1.9.3.8\app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/configurableswatches/catalog/product/view/type/options/conf

**Please help me to solve this. I am new in Magento CMS.**

Comment: Hi,
from connect manager I'm trying to update modules from 1.8.1 to 1.9.38. I'm starting with module Mage_All_Latest, after some package correctly upgraded I got this error

Comment: please also post error log file.. or  place `downloader folder` from fresh Magento download

Comment: where to find error log?

Comment: no log directory in /var for me

Comment: any error log file ??

Comment: Is it possible to upload the files directly by downloading through [magento's release page](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download)?